# Ignoring cucumber-rails directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, gitignore

I may have missed this somewhere.

My rails 3.2 project has a cucumber-rails directory that has many files containing paths/settings specific to my machine. I wouldn't have thought twice, but the directory has a ton of gems in it too. (folder is something like 150Mb)

```
my_project
|
|--- app/
|--- config/
|--- config.ru
|--- db/
|--- cucumber-rails/
|    +--- ruby/
|          |
|          +--- 1.9.1
|                |
|                +--- (and more)
```

I don't know why this folder even exists since none of my other rails apps seem to have one.

I'm very inclined to gitignore and purge this entire directory from my git indexes rather than to have it in the shared project and in history.

Are there any compelling reasons to ***not*** ignore the entire cucumber-rails directory? I just don't want to have a useless repo.

**I updated this post just to be a little clearer as to what I am seeing**

Comment: Rather than ignoring a portion of the app that consumes 2/3 of total project disk area, I have completely removed the cucumber-rails directory from my project. My logic here is that Rails plugin developers would not have designed something in the heart of this framework that contains so much local configuration data. 
  
Since the directory delete my tests seem to be running fine with the expected pass / fail results. I'm going to just assume I somehow introduced the directory in error. I'm not answering my own question because *really* I'm just guessing at this point.

Comment: I think you were right in deleting the folder. cucumber-rails gem doesn't create the folder. From the directory structure, it seems more like an rvm gemset folder that got moved here by mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears this directory got there in error, an anomaly.

I deleted it and there has been no negative impact on the project so I am indicating that as the answer to my question.